# IMAP account with 2 folders for "Deleted" and "Deleted Messages"

Tags: email, imap

Is there a universal name which should be used for "Trash" messages?

E.g when testing the same email account on Thunderbird, Outlook and iPhone. When deleting a message they all move this into a different named folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the IMAP standard does not dictate the name for folders.  There are some extensions used by some servers (notably GMail's XLIST) to help with this problem.

Most email clients can be reconfigured to use a different folder.   For example, in Thunderbird's account settings, you can change the option "move deleted mail to [folder]".  Apple Mail has a "Use this folder for Trash" menu item.